# Irregular "Request Timed Out" Ping Response

Tags: networking, network-programming, ping, icmp

I am running 3 PCs on ADSL 2 router. I have 4 MBPS Broadband. When all the PCs run simultaneously, slow browsing is experienced.

On pinging Google DNS `ping 8.8.8.8 -t` I receive irregular "Request Timed Out" response after few replies.

I inquired my Internet Service Provider and they say yes it's normal. I want to make sure whether its OK to receive irregular "Request Timed Out" responses or if there's any fault in wiring, router or isp?

[image: Ping Screenshot]

Comment: may be your ping rated as a ping of death so it will go timeout then again continue .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the browsing speed is not only depend on ISP but also how good router you
are using .

when you connecting three PCs and using it simultaneously , your router 
have to serve them one by one it cannot server all PCs at same time
causing loss of ping .